# Compile assemblies with restrictive access

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

Is it possible to compile an assembly to either:
only include certain code parts 
OR
Allow access to certain code based on a credential?

I have an assembly that is redistributed. Certain applications will only use/have access to certain functionality and other will need more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make internal types accessible for certain assemblies using the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute. But this attribute's intent is to be used in unit test scenarios.

Comment: Can you control what gets included in the compilation? Can you say include this and not that.

Comment: No. I think what you want can only be achieved by code access security. But I'm not so familiar with CAS.

Comment: This looking like the answer to what I need. Cheers